# Electron Application Built on macOS for windows is not working on installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, electron, electron-builder

I built an electron application on macOS for windows using electron-builder.
script: npm run pre-build-electron && electron-builder build --win --publish never
I ran this script and generated .exe file.
when i tried installting this .exe file in windows the installer runs for a second or two and after that this error is being thrown.

Error: Windows is searching for xxxx.exe. To locate the file yourself, click Browse.
-> On the top of the error the title is Missing Shortcut.

And when i try to browse i can only find uninstaller of that specific app.

This is my build code

```js
{
    "appId": "org.management.system",
    "productName": "Management System",
    
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "electron/main.js",
      "package.json",
      "icon.ico"
  
    ],
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "github",
        "owner": "xxxxx",
        "repo": "frontend-release"
      }
    ],
    "extends": null,
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
   
  }
```

I cannot find the reason why the installer is not working when i build it in macOS. The same build when built on a windows system with same code and package.json everything works fine. Can anyone help me identify the reason.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm also annoyed by this problem.

```
"electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
```

downgrade electron-builder will fix this. This is probably a bug of electron-builder.

```
"electron-builder": "^23.3.3",
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to specify an arch property for the windows build (x64):

```
"build": {
  // other properties
  "win": {
    "target": [
      {
        "target": "nsis",
        "arch": [
          "x64"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```